# D3 Javascript Performance in visualising huge XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, d3.js

I am trying to visualise an XML file which is nearly 1 GB as a graph of nodes and links using D3 Javascript. I am using `mac 10.5.8`. So far, I could manage to print out the content of the file which is: `[Object Element]` . It took nearly a minute for printing this statement since it loads and reads this XML file. My question, if I want to visualise this file as a graph of circles and links, how can I improve the performance of visualising this file? It seems it may take really long time to display the graph of this huge file. Is there anyway to improve the performance of visualising such a big graph of big data? Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How many nodes and links? Above 500 nodes and links it will start to be though to visualise with D3.

Comment: I would say much more than this. The XML file itself is 1 GB. Do you think I will have some problems with visualising this huge amount of nodes and links or problems with the D3 performance? The XML file is huge.

Comment: You're not going to get good performance with that amount of data. Just loading it is going to be slow.

Comment: Should I say now that there would not be anyway to get better performance, Lars? For example, parsing the file in better way or something similar to this?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the data that's in there, but unless you can get it down to a few MB I don't think that performance will be too good in the end.

Comment: Sorry about this, Lars. The file is dblp.xml. It contains a huge number of tags such as: author, article, title, page, number, url, year, etc. I believe it is like millions of lines in that xml file. Sometimes Firefox crashes when I run the D3 Javascript program. I am afraid it will not be that good performance.

Comment: Given that you can't display all nodes and links at once anyway, you could retrieve only the data for an author and its connections and load the rest of the data on demand. This would require a servlet or similar that provides this functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lars for your reply. I will think of it from this perspective and keep you updated.

Comment: Definitely load that XML on the server as Lars said - in a DB or whatever ad hoc data structure). An approach, other than the micro-explorer one suggested, might consist in some aggregation task that runs on the backend and using a visualization library to show the result. Maybe next to it you can have a micro-explorer widget to inspect the aggregated item.

Answer (score 0):

Simply downloading a 1GB file takes a significant amount of time. Parsing adds to that.

Depending on what you're doing with the data -- and how willing you are to pay download costs again if you change your mind about what information is relevant -- you may be able to optimize the parsing somewhat by filtering it as it comes in and only building data models for the portions you actually need.

Or, as others note, you can do that extraction on the server side and bring down only the immediately relevant portion. Which will reduce both network and parsing time, though again you're going to need to spend additional time if you need data that didn't come down during the first request. This is one of the things XQuery is useful for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have been recommended to look through Javaserver Faces (JSF). It has the Servlet Faces which helps to handle this huge amount of data. Would you have any recommendation for me?